# How call a method with actionname attribute from client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a method from client side, my controller method has [ActionName] attribute on it. But there is already a same action method with that name.But I need to call this method MyMethod() by ajax call. Is this possible without creating any new method or making any changes to attributes of MyMethod().

Here is controller code:

```
public ActionResult PaymentMethod()
{
    // Some logic
}

[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost, ActionName("Paymentmethod")]
[FormValueRequired("applydiscountcouponcode")]
public ActionResult MyMethod(string dd, FormCollection ff)
{
    // Rest of logic
}
```

Javacript Code:

```
function ApplyDiscountCode() {
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/controllername/Paymentmethod", // call method 
        data: { dd: $("#inpCode").val(), ff: null },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

This is not working, as it is calling the first method only.

Comment: @DarshakGajjar how is it duplicate with the link you provided ?

Comment: You can call like that if the other one is not `HttpPost`. You can't use the same action name which already exists in the same controller.

Comment: I think the correct controller method should be inferred from the request type and the data. So I think your problem is not with action name, but with that the data is not sent or processed correctly. You should debug server-side what is in the `HttpRequest.RouteData` for example as a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be changed the code to:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PaymentMethod()
{
    // Some logic
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
[FormValueRequired("applydiscountcouponcode")]
public ActionResult PaymentMethod(string dd, FormCollection ff)
{
    // Rest of logic
}
```

As you're using Asp.net Core, you might change the attributes of my method as below:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost("PaymentMethod")]
[FormValueRequired("applydiscountcouponcode")]
public ActionResult MyMethod(string dd, FormCollection ff)
{
    // Rest of logic
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: This error is coming  when I am using above code for this line [HttpPost("PaymentMethod")]

System.Web.Mvc,HtttpPostAttribute doesn't contain a constructor that takes 1 argument.

Comment: In case you are using Asp.net MVC 4 or 5, you should use the first way.

Comment: I am using MVC 5.2.3.0 and it my it is nopcommerce project.